# Submit / Validation Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to validate a form at the point of clicking submit. There are a number of inputs which need validating which are all assigned the class .ipv4val. The issue I have is that I cant seem to add the 'bad' class to the single input element that has failed the validation ?

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var REGEX = /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$/;  
    if (REGEX.test($(".ipv4val").val())) {
      return true;
    }
else {
      $(this).addClass("bad");
  return false;
   }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe because `$(this)` applied to `form` instead of the individual elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```js
$("form").submit(function() {
    var REGEX = /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$/;
    var ok=true;
    $(".ipv4val").each(function(){
        if (!REGEX.test($(this).val())) {
            $(this).addClass("bad");
            ok = false;
        }
    });
    return ok;
};
```

Comment: Spot on. Like the idea of using the return variables. Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Look out for your use of: `$(this).addClass("bad")`

`$(this)` is the `form` element at the time of its execution. Try using the element ID of the input.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the [jquery.validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), instead of rolling your own validation?

Comment: good shout, I should really read up on how this is done. I suppose I thought it would be quicker to write my own.